# Duplicate request IDs in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, chromium

Chromium/Puppeteer *seems* to be reusing request IDs.

I'm counting the requests and response IDs, I was expecting to get two of each ID (one on the request, then the same on on its `response.request()._requestId`) but I'm finding that there are more.

I'm collecting the metrics with these two events:

```js
    page.on('request', (request) => {
        const requestId = request._requestId;
        if (counter[requestId])
            counter[requestId]++;
        else
            counter[requestId.toString()] = 1;
    });

    page.on('response', (response) => {

        const requestId = response.request()._requestId;

        if (counter[requestId])
            counter[requestId]++;
        else
            counter[requestId] = 1;
    });
```

Results from stringifying the `counter` object:

```
{
    "750DF247357DA37DCCBE84ACEB1BB07E": 4,
    "22596.2": 2,
    "22596.3": 2,
    "22596.4": 2,
    "22596.5": 2,
    "22596.6": 2,
    "22596.7": 2,
    "22596.12": 2,
    "22596.13": 2,
    "22596.14": 2,
    "22596.19": 2,
    "22596.22": 2,
    "22596.35": 2,
    "22596.36": 2,
    "22596.37": 2,
    "22596.38": 2,
    "22596.39": 2,
    "22596.40": 2,
    "22596.41": 2,
    "22596.42": 2,
    "22596.43": 2,
    "22596.44": 2,
    "22596.45": 2,
    "22596.46": 2,
    "22596.47": 2,
    "22596.48": 2,
    "22596.49": 2,
    "22596.50": 6,
    "22596.51": 3,
    "22596.52": 3,
    "22596.53": 3,
    "22596.54": 3,
    "22596.55": 3,
    "22596.58": 2,
    "9D29F14302C8451741C1169CB32CDF21": 4,
    "581B16FB 5232782601F519C9558B218B": 4,
    "22596.60": 4,
    "22596.61": 2,
    "22596.62": 2,
    "22596.63": 2,
    "22596.65": 2,
    "22596.67": 2,
    "22596.68": 6,
    "22596.69": 2,
    "22596.70": 2,
    "22596.74": 2,
    "22596.76": 2,
    "22596.78": 2,
    "22596.79": 2,
    "22596.80": 2,
    "22596.86": 2,
    "22596.87": 2,
    "22596.88": 2,
    "22596. 89": 2,
    "22596.90": 2,
    "22596.91": 2,
    "22596.92": 2,
    "22596.93": 2,
    "22596.94": 2,
    "22596.95": 2,
    "22596.96": 2,
    "22596.97": 2,
    "817C68343178670A2608D3103FBBED3E": 4,
    "22596.98": 3,
    "22596.99": 2,
    "22596.100": 2,
}
```

Is the `_requestId` supposed to be a unique number within the page?
What

Comment: It should be unique. I'd think that the event is being triggered twice. Do you have a public URL to test that out?

Comment: @hardkoded I don't, I'll get a demo written for you though.

Comment: That would be awesome!

Comment: It's not unique for me as well. The interception id, that was suggested by Jonathan's answer below, is unique, though.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem... to solve i coded as follows:

In "on request", use: `const requestId = request._interceptionId`

In "on response", use: `const requestId = response.request()._interceptionId`

I hope it works

Answer (score 0):

without interception, it's not secure.
if you don't want to enable interception.
you should create your own request id for mapping.

```
function getRequestId(request: HTTPRequest) {
    return hash({
      url: request.url(),
      method: request.method(),
      headers: request.headers(),
      initiator: request.initiator(),
    })
}
```

`hash` is any object hashing function.

Maybe you can try this: https://github.com/unjs/ohash

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The suggestion by Jonathan helped, but I was still seeing weird behavior, such as no responses arriving for some requests.

When I examined the specific requests, I discovered that they were all related to fonts: download of TTF, download of WOFF, and in one case - the raw font data was in the URL itself (i.e. the URL started with `data:font/x-font...`.

So just ignoring these requests in my data structures fixed the issue for me (and now also `response.request()._requestId` and even the `response.request()` object itself can be used to match previous requests.